# Queryset not displayed in django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am creating a Django application and trying to include more search boxes in Django web admin interface for a specific model, so that users can simultaniously search more fields. For example, users can enter in one search box the name of the city, and in another search box the name of the street, and all model instances which have corresponding city and street are shown in browser after 'Search' button is hit. Default admin web interface has only one search box. I've added three search boxes in `change_list.html` file, and when I enter some data in those search boxes in browser and hit 'Search', a proper URL is formed (with query string containing those three input parameters by which the search shoould be done). Then I capture those input parameters in `queryset` method which I have overriden in my class that extends `models.AdminModel` calss, perform query set filtering and finally return the filtered queryset. Now, the problem is that the filtered query set is simply not shown on the web page (web interface of my model) after the search process is done, it says that no matches were found. But I am definately sure that my filtered query set contains data beacues I print it in command line just before the `return` command of `queryset` method is executed, and it prints correct data.

Here is my `queryset` method:

```
def queryset(self, request):

    qs = super(UkopcanjeAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    if "mjesto" in request.GET:
        lokacija = request.GET.get('mjesto',None)
        if lokacija:
            qs = qs.filter(mjesto__icontains=lokacija)

    if "ulica" in request.GET:
        ulica = request.GET.get('ulica',None)
        if ulica:
            qs = qs.filter(ulica__icontains=ulica)

    if "naziv" in request.GET:
        naziv = request.GET.get('naziv',None)
        if naziv:
            qs = qs.filter(naziv__icontains=naziv)

    print qs #this prints correct filtered data
    return qs
```

Why isn't filtered query set shown in web interface?

**EDIT :** Thanks to my friend, I've finally managed to solve the problem. And solution is quite simple, all I had to do is move the whole code of `queryset` method to `get_search_results` method, and along filtered queryset return `false`  boolean parameter (because `get_search_results` method returns two parameters). So if anybody wants to customize the search process in Django, the `get_search_results` method should be used. There you can access query string argumnets and retreive some data the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `get_queryset` but not `queryset` method.

```
def get_queryset(request):
   #your code here
   queryset = super(UkopcanjeAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
   if 'miesto' in request.GET:
       print 'Yes'
       return queryset
   else:
       print 'No'
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) is some short explanation from Django docs.

Comment: But can I access URL parameters in `get_queryset` method?

Comment: @programmer I have updated my answer. It take 'request' as argument and you can acces GET and all other that you need from there.

Comment: I've changed `queryset` to `get_queryset`, but unfortunately behaviour is the same. Filtered query set contains correct data, but it is simply not displayed in browser... It is interesting that it works well only if I have one parameter in my URL query string, for example localhost:8000/admin/mainApp/some_model/?location=someCity, but if I have more than one parameter, filtered query set is not displayed...